# WCF Service Access Denied for Microsoft office introp word Application

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ms-word

I was working on file conversion of doc to docx in my using WCF service that are hosted on IIS. When I was trying to create an object for

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
```

I got this error

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {000209FF-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I also did **DCOM Config** that I found solution from other posts but still I have same problem.

Comment: Why would you need to configure dcom? There is nothing going cross-server except the WCF call. Do you have the MS Office primary interop assemblies installed? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/kh3965hw(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: @Tom Thanks  for your response. Yes I have installed PIAs already.

Comment: I know this doesn't help but Microsoft do no support running Word or other office apps on the server. Their recommended approach is to use OpenXML for server-side document assembly

Comment: Thanks Sir , but sir openXML dosen't handle the .doc format. and also after searching a lot I knew that I have to puraches third party tool or I have to design my own to convert it and use it in my work